# First order variation and total variation of a function/stochastic process

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

The notions of first-order variation and total variation of a function or a stochastic process are equated in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=_208xZ5YJH4C&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=total%20variation%20%22first%20order%20variation%22&source=bl&ots=cNloDikRtn&sig=b41hcdH9mOeI09cbygxIkxv2OUo&hl=en&ei=YUfRTuWsJujw0gHru8zoDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=total%20variation%20%22first%20order%20variation%22&f=false).

However, I found their definitions different from two other sources:

1. In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Definitions) the total variation of a function $f$ from time $0$ to time
   $T$ is defined as $$
           \sup_\Pi \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} | f(t_{i+1})-f(t_i) | .  $$
2. In Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-time Models by
   Steve Shreve, the first-order variation of a function or stochastic
   process $f$ from time $0$ to time $T$ is defined as: $$ \lim_{||\Pi|| \to
       0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} [f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j)] $$ where $$\Pi=[t_0, t_1,
       \dots, t_n] \text{ and } 0 \leq t_0 < t_1 < \cdots  < t_n = T$$ and
   $$||\Pi||= \max_{j=0,\dots, n-1} (t_{j+1} -t_j).$$

Are they two different definitions, or equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: Equivalent. Which implication is unclear to you?

Comment: @Didier: Under what conditions on the function or stochastic process $f$, are they equivalent? How does $\sup$ become $\lim$?

Comment: Forget the stochastic side, this is a *deterministic* result. How does the total variation $V(f,\Pi)$ varies when $\Pi$ is refined?

Comment: @Didier: I guess you expect me to say "non-decreasing"? I don't know why. Plus: can the relation between the partitions not be restricted to refinement? Does it require that $f$ is some kind of continuous?

Comment: It is indeed just a deterministic result nothing to do with stochastic calculus. W.r.t. your questions: 1. it is non-decreasing because $$|f(t_{i+1})-f(t_{i})|\leq |f(t_{i+1})-f(t_{i+1/2})|+|f(t_{i+1/2})-f(t_i)|$$ where $t_{i+1/2}$ is a new point. $$ $$2. For partitions $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ there exists $\Pi= \Pi_1\cup\Pi_2$ which is refinement of both, so $$\|\Pi\|\leq\min(\|\Pi_1\|,\|\Pi_2\|)$$ and $$V(f,\Pi)\geq\max(V(f,\Pi_1),V(f,\Pi_2)).$$

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks! Why is $\Pi= \Pi_1\cup\Pi_2$ a partition?

Comment: Well, partition is a set of points $\Pi = \{a=t_0,\dots,t_n = b\}$ so taking a union of two partitions as sets of points you still obtain a partition, don't you?

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: Ethan: Great. You could write your solution and post it as an answer.