# Finite variation continuous function, enough to look at rational points?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that you have a real continuous function $f$ on $[0,T]$, that is of finite variation, that is:

$\sup\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N(\gamma)}|f(x_{i+1}(\gamma))-f(x_i(\gamma))|:\gamma \text{ is a partition of } [0,T]\}=K <\infty$.

Then for any $\epsilon$ you can find a partition of $[0,T]$, $\gamma_\epsilon$, such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N(\gamma_\epsilon)}|f(x_{i+1}(\gamma_\epsilon)-f(x_i(\gamma_\epsilon)))|>K-\epsilon$.

I am wondering if it is possible to choose that partition points of $\gamma_\epsilon$ rational? Or are there counterexamples where this would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r>0$ .Then corresponding to $r>0$ there exists a partition $P=\{0=a_0<a_1<a_2<\dots a_n=T\}$  such that

$\sum_{i=0}^n|f(a_{i+1)}-f(a_i)|>K-r$.

Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so for each $a_i;0\le i\le n$ there exists $q_i\in \Bbb Q$ such that $|a_i-q_i|<\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in \Bbb N$

Also $f$ is continuous so $|f(a_i)-f(q_i)|<\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in \Bbb N$.

Then the new partition becomes $P^{'}=\{0=q_0<q_1<q_2<\dots q_n=T\}$  .

The sum  $\sum_{i=0}^n|f(a_{i+1)}-f(a_i)|$ can be made $\epsilon $ close to $\sum_{i=0}^n|f(q_{i+1)}-f(q_i)|$ depending on our choice of $q_i's$ for each $\epsilon>0$
.

Thus
$\sum_{i=0}^n|f(q_{i+1)}-f(q_i)|>K-r$